# copy variable data to new file using batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, dos

THis is my code

```
for /l %%i in (1, 1, %N%) do (
echo !v%%i!
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%l in ("!v%%i!") do (    
echo %%l >> Linux.cpp     ) 
)
```

Here i want to copy data in %%l to linux.cpp file
Now what happening is if %%l contain abc.cpp this name is stored in linux.cpp. Here i want to store contents in abc.cpp to linux.cpp.

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the *contents* of the file to be appended to `Linux.cpp` then use `type` (which displays the contents of a file) instead of `echo`.

e.g. `type %%l >> Linux.cpp`

Comment: Thanks for your help.. Its copying the dat ain file but my intension is to delete CR from windows file.
By giving echo only its deleting CR. In type its not deleting carriage return

Comment: If i give sample.cpp instead of ("!v%%i!") in for loop its working perfectly.

Please help what may be the error